# Why does parent's !important lose?

Tags: css, css-specificity

The `color` property of the parent block has an `!important` declaration. Why does the child's property take precedence? How to explain it?

I see explanations of specificity, but I don't understand how to apply them to this particular case.

Perhaps I missed some basic position in the documentation ...

```css
div {
  color: purple !important;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
span {
  color: red; /* Why does parent's `!important` lose? */
}
```

```html
<div>
  Parent
  <span>Child</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Per [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Directly_targeted_elements_versus_inherited_styles):

> Styles for a directly targeted element will always take precedence over inherited styles, regardless of the specificity of the inherited rule.

In your example, the `span` selector *directly targets* the child element, and thus takes precedence over the inherited style of the parent `div` selector. Now to explain why `!important` doesn't change this.

The reason why the `!important` is disregarded here is that `!important` takes precedence over all other declarations *only if it's the same type of element being selected*. It doesn't matter here because the child is a `span` which is a different element, not another `div`. If the child **were to be a `div`, then the `!important`, then `!important` would apply**:

```css
div {
  color: purple !important;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
div > div {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  Parent
  <div>Child</div>
</div>
```

In the example above, the `div > div` rule should, in theory, make the child red because of specificity, but since the `!important` is under a `div` selector, thus selecting the same element type, it will override the more specific rule.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me where this provision is mentioned by W3C?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Sure. In the meantime, I did edit my answer since there were parts that were a bit off.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky In [Section 6.4 of the CSS Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade): *"more specific selectors will override more general ones."* - thus directly targeted and thus *more specific* selectors override more general ones such as the parent selector here.

Comment: At the same time, paragraph 6.4.2 says that an `!important` declaration `takes precedence over a normal declaration`. Where does it follow that child's declaration is still stronger than parent's `!important`?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky As I mentioned in the post, it's because the child is a span, not another div, so !important has no effect. The !important only takes precedence over other declarations if the select the same element type. If you have a div child instead of a span, !important will take precedence, as in my post.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I would be happy to find text on W3C, similar to the quote from MDN. Perhaps it is such a common place that it is not there. But without this I can not make an absolutely strict explanation.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky - The text on W3C is there but it's put in rather different, more precise, but perhaps somewhat less readable, terms. Read [section 6.1 of the CSS 2.2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#value-stages)

Comment: ... In particular 6.1.1 step 1 says "If the cascade results in a value, use it." Inheritance only applies either when step 1 results in a value of "inherit", or as "otherwise .. " in step 2.

Comment: @Alohci It's very intresting. Now I understand the situation as follows: If a child have his own property, he ignores the parent's instructions. Neither `!important`, nor the specificity of the parent does not concern him in any way. If the child does not care (his property is undefined) or the child intentionally imitates the parent (`inherit`), then he borrows the property of the parent. Then the parent's `!important` affects the result for the parent, and the child copies this result. What would you like to correct?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky - That's very nearly right. Except that if the child's property is undefined, it borrows the property of the parent - only if the property is one that is defined as [inherited](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/about.html#inherited-prop). So, for instance, the color property is inherited, so it takes its parent's color if it's otherwise undefined, but margin properties aren't inherited, so the child takes its initial values (i.e. 0) if they are undefined.

Comment: @Alohci If you post your comments as an answer, I will choose it as a solution. You brought the position from the specification, from which the answer directly follows and which explains what exactly happens in this case.

Answer (score 1):

@Alohci cited [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511582/why-does-parents-important-lose#comment76021355_44511627) a link to the documentation:

#### W3C CSS 2.1 Specification. [6.1.1 Specified values](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specified-value)

> User agents must first assign a specified value to each property based
>   on the following mechanisms (in order of precedence):
>
> 1. If the [cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) results in a value, use it.
> 2. Otherwise, if the property is [inherited](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#inheritance) and
>      the element is not the root of the document tree, use the computed
>      value of the parent element.
> 3. Otherwise use the property's initial value. The initial value of each property is indicated in the property's definition.

So now I understand the situation as follows:

Parent properties do not directly affect the child, but the browser uses them:

1. when the child requires it (`inherit`);
2. when the desired property is not specified anywhere (neither by the child, nor by the user, nor by the browser itself) and is defined as inherited.

Therefore, the specificity and importance of the parent does not compete with the specificity of the child. There is a winner at the level of the parent and a winner at the level of the child, but they do not know about each other. Only when the browser uses the parent property for the child element, it becomes important who won at the parent level.

In short, the parent element does not affect, but specifies an example. The child does not obey, but imitates when he sees fit.